# Excel Find the Closest Text Value

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have data collected from an website form, where parents are required to type in the school their child attends. Unfortunately there are many different text combinations for the same school, and I need to find the closest school name as possible.

Consider the following example:

```
          A                         B
     Parents Typing        Official Names of School
     ----------------------------------------------
1    Erin Woods School        Erin Woods School
2    Erin Woods Elementary        St. Catherine Elementary School
3    Erin Woods        Monsignor A. J. Hetherington Elementary School
4    Erinwoods elementary        Catherine Nichols Gunn School
5    Erin Woods        Huntington Hills School
6    ERINWOODS SCHOOL        Mayland Heights School
7    ERINWOORDS SCHOOL        Mount View School
8    erinwoods school        North Haven School
9    Erin wood school         Queen Elizabeth School
10    Erinwoods Elementary        Ecole de la Rose Sauvage
```

I have 10 different ways of parents identifying "Erin Woods School". My attempts as using an 'index'&'match' combination has limited success, and can often pick up other school names (as illustrated in column 'B').

Perhaps there's an answer here, but I am unable to get it to work.
[Excel Find the largest partial value in an indexed list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149352/excel-find-the-largest-partial-value-in-an-indexed-list)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have over 20 schools to comb through, and re-typing the parents entries would be exhausting.

Comment: Why don't you just change the web form so that it has a drop-down list of the valid school names.  (Any time you allow people to type free-form text you are going to have problems.)  The parents will appreciate it, because it is easier for them to select one entry out of a list of 20 then to have to type the name in.

Comment: Thanks Yow,... we have thought of that and will try do that in the future.  There's over 2000 schools, and a list would be very cumbersome to be scrolling through. We'll need to find a way to categorize them or separate them by the alphabet. Nevertheless, we have this data to work through as-is.

Comment: Ahh - 2000 is definitely different to the 20 mentioned in the question ("I have over 20 schools").  I saw your 2000 in the comment to pnuts' answer and I thought you must have been referring to what is shown in column A of the data in the question, i.e. the data to be cleansed.

Answer (score 1):

For your sample data the following should work:

```
=IF(SEARCH("woo",A2),$B$2)
```

copied down to suit.

Maybe you should provide parents with your (numbered) list of schools and ask them to enter a number instead.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response,... let me better describe the scale I'm working with.  'Erin Woods' is just one of over 20 schools I need to properly/consistently rename amongst hundreds of entries from parents. 
 Column 'B' has over 2000 entries, and there will be alot of "woo"s to be found.

Comment: Thanks pnuts!... I wasn't aware of this product but it looks like it'll do the trick. (Now I have to figure out how to use it.)

Comment: True,... that approach should take care of many, leaving the Catholic schools (that start with "St. ...") to manually correct.